# Logs of executed Query in SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

Database having 5 users
All users are running queries on database and we need to find what are the things all users doing like

```
(
LOGIN_NAME,
    QUERY_START_TIME,
    QUERY_END_TIME,
    total_elapsed_time,
    QUERY
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to query [sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor).

Short answer, because it only holds the last 10,000 queries in a ring buffer.

Otherwise, use [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/monitoring/how-to-monitor-using-azure-monitor#dedicated-sql-pool-logs) and log the DMVs to storage for longer term analytics.

Comment: We need to maintain Audit table for all the users (i.e, A user performed some select command , B user performed update command , C user executed Sp's ) along with username , database name

Comment: Synapse (new name for DW) has only one database, so drop that requirement. The rest is satisfied by the DMV I listed, it has columns for user, command, SP, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ron Dunn